# FlushAction and Lazy attribute

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, lazy-loading, castle-activerecord

I have a Solution 'MySolution' in VS. In one project 'Domain' I have defined de following classes:

```
public class CarBase
{
    public virtual void Foo();
}

public class Car : CarBase
{
    [BelongsTo(..., Lazy=FetchWhen.OnInvoke)]
    public virtual Person person { get; set; };

    public override void Foo()
    {
        person.HasCar = true; // #1
        person.Save();
    }
}
```

In another project of 'MySolution', named 'Bussines', I have the following code:

```
using(SessionScope session = new SessionScope(FlushAction.Never))
{
    CarBase carBase = CarBase.GetItem(123);
    carBase.Foo();
}
```

Ok, so what's the problem?.
That code fails in #1 due to 'Failing to access a lazy attribute'. I don't understand why if that object is in the same *SessionScope* of the *GetItem*.

Additionaly, if in the same code I change *FlushAction.Never* to *FlushAction.Auto*, the error dissapears.

I'd like to know why this happens?. Why should *FlushAction* property change the way lazy loading is handeled?

I don't know if the overriden method, or the fact that both codes are in different solutions would matter. I guess not, but ORMs are quite suprising.

Thanks in advance.

PD: If in the next line of *GetItem* I do:

```
if(carBase is Car)
     ((Car)carBase).HasCar.ToString();
```

Even with *FlushAction.Never*, it also fixes the problem.

Comment: Is this a Web Project or Windows Form?

Answer (score 0):

Found this article in the CastleRecord docs. Hope it helps.

http://docs.castleproject.org/Active%20Record.The-ByteCode.ashx?HL=fetchwhen,oninvoke

Also, it mentions that **Session management of lazy properties and relationships is not currently supported. These must still be accessed from within the original SessionScope.**

Comment: In my code the lazy attribute is accessed from the original SessionScope that retrived it from DB.